# Why can't I access an NSTextField object within viewDidLoad()

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield, nsviewcontroller, nssplitviewcontroller

Why is it that I get a "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error, suggesting the `NSTextField` object (text1) is not there if I try to update it during the `viewDidLoad()` of an `NSView` class?

```
class SplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var text1: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        text1.stringValue = "View loaded OK"
    }


    @IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: NSButton) {

        text1.stringValue = "Button was pressed"
    }
}
```

If I comment out the line `text1.stringValue = "View loaded OK"` from the `viewDidLoad()` function then it runs fine and I can access the object  using an `@IBAction` linked to a button on the view - so it is connected OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32170457/6382196).

You will need to unwrap the `NSTextField` in this case your `text1`.

Comment: Thanks Joāo, that worked. Why does it need to be unwrapped in the `viewDidLoad()` function but not in `buttonPress...`?